# Adding the userControl to the DockPanel didn't effect Dynamically in Wpf

Tags: wpf, oop, events

I am new to Wpf. One UserControl (Wpf UserControl) is added to
 the DockPanel and in some action O replaced the first  UserControl
 with another UserControl in DockPanel dynamically. But the first
 UserContorl remains visible and the second UserControl in not showing
 in DockPanel.

I don't know the correct behavior of how I can be
 loaded dynamically.  I added this code (this code is executed well)
 but it doesn't reflect the action to display  "CtlAddEmployee"
 control in Dockpanel.

```
CtlAddEmployee frm2 = new CtlAddEmployee(str);
        DockPanelInRibbon.Children.Clear();
        DockPanelInRibbon.Children.Add(frm2);
```

For full details how it is working is asked in my previous question
 in detailed way:

[Loading another userControl in wpf Ribbon Window when the we click on DataGrid row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10818005/loading-another-usercontrol-in-wpf-ribbon-window-when-the-we-click-on-datagrid-r)

Please provide the solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yaa here i need to refer old object but not the new created object for the corresponding class reference...

For that better to use parameterized constructors..